# Pandas GroupBy - Show only groups with more than one unique feature-value

Tags: python, pandas, compare, unique, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame `df_things` that looks like this and i want to predict the quality of the classification before the training

```
A    B     C      CLASS
-----------------------
al1  bal1  cal1   Ship
al1  bal1  cal1   Ship
al1  bal2  cal2   Ship
al2  bal2  cal2   Cow
al3  bal3  cal3   Car
al1  bal2  cal3   Car
al3  bal3  cal3   Car
```

I want to group rows by classes so that i have an idea of the distribution of the features. I do this with (for example, on col "B"),

```
df_B = df_things.groupby('CLASS').B.value_counts()
```

which gives me the results

```
CLASS  B 
-------------
ship   bal1  2 
       bal2  1
cow    bal2  2
car    bal2  1
       bal3  2
```

What I want to to is to visualize only groups that have more than one value so that it looks like this:

```
CLASS  B 
-------------
ship   bal1  2 
       bal2  1
car    bal2  1
       bal3  2
```

I'm a little bit stuck, so any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to filter groups that have an `nunique` count over 1.

```
v = df_things.groupby('CLASS').B.value_counts()
v[v.groupby(level=0).transform('nunique').gt(1)]

CLASS  B   
Car    bal3    2
       bal2    1
Ship   bal1    2
       bal2    1
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much - exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: And thank you for the editing of my post. It helps me to ask my questions in a more precise way!

Comment: @FelTry2 Just being a good citizen of the site. Keep the questions rolling!

Answer (score 2):

Solution from `crosstab`

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.CLASS,df.B)
s[s.ne(0).sum(1)>1].replace(0,np.nan).stack()
CLASS  B   
Car    bal2    1.0
       bal3    2.0
Ship   bal1    2.0
       bal2    1.0
dtype: float64
```